# post equivalent in scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

What is the syntax of 'post' in scripted pipeline comparing to declarative pipeline?
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

Answer (score 89, accepted):

For scripted pipeline, everything must be written programmatically and most of the work is done in the `finally` block:

`Jenkinsfile` (Scripted Pipeline):

```groovy
node {
    try {
        stage('Test') {
            sh 'echo "Fail!"; exit 1'
        }
        echo 'This will run only if successful'
    } catch (e) {
        echo 'This will run only if failed'

        // Since we're catching the exception in order to report on it,
        // we need to re-throw it, to ensure that the build is marked as failed
        throw e
    } finally {
        def currentResult = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS'
        if (currentResult == 'UNSTABLE') {
            echo 'This will run only if the run was marked as unstable'
        }

        def previousResult = currentBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.result
        if (previousResult != null && previousResult != currentResult) {
            echo 'This will run only if the state of the Pipeline has changed'
            echo 'For example, if the Pipeline was previously failing but is now successful'
        }

        echo 'This will always run'
    }
}
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#finishing-up

Comment: isn't there a better way - are we expected to replicate this all this logic across our scripted pipelines?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Thats alot of a "code noise" to browse through every time

Comment: Can the try block encapsulate multiple stages? That way I only need to make this monstrosity once for the whole pipeline.

Comment: sad overhead, since we would like to execute post actions after multiple stages..

Comment: If you are using scripted, you can use shared libraries. You still need to do the try-finally song and dance, but at least you don't have to repeat the whole logic.

Comment: Since we're catching the exception in order to report on it, we need to re-throw it, to ensure that the build is marked as failed

Comment: mindflowing!! this is leaps and bounds better than post

Comment: This is the best and also not the entirely correct answer. The `currentBuild.result` and `currentBuild.currentResult` have incorrect value in `finally` block, see: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-47403, and a few other reports.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here's another source with similar code: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/

Comment: For the full disclosure, if the error is thrown from `finally` block, your calling script will see that exception and not the original one.  The implication: without proper reporting it may be hard to pinpoint the real problem with the build.

Comment: This is great, though sadly despite `throw e` the stack trace is not printed c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069379/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-dump-errors and https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44808 for possible solutions

Comment: P.S. sorry actually the stack trace _is_ printed normally, however if anything in the `finally` block fails then it is silently swallowed and superseded by that error.

Answer (score 17):

You can modify @jf2010 solution so that it looks a little neater (in my opinion)

```
try {
    pipeline()
} catch (e) {
    postFailure(e)
} finally {
    postAlways()
}


def pipeline(){
    stage('Test') {
        sh 'echo "Fail!"; exit 1'
    }
    println 'This will run only if successful'
}

def postFailure(e) {
    println "Failed because of $e"
    println 'This will run only if failed'

}

def postAlways() {
    println 'This will always run'
}
```