# jenkinsfile send email notifications

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I was trying to send email alert whenever there is a build failed for Jenkins

```
node ('abc') {
  stage ('checkout'){
   some codes inside
   }

  stage ('build'){
    some code inside
  }

  stage ('test') {
    some code inside
   }

  stage ('deploy'){
  some code inside
  }

  post {
    failure {
        mail bcc: '', body: '''Hi, 

        The pipeline at Jenkins has failed. Pleas go over to the Jenkins and 
         check it out.

         Thanks!''', cc: '', from: '', replyTo: '', subject: 'The pipeline has failed!', to: 'abc@gmail.com'
        }
    }

}
```

And I have error message of

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among
>   steps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [post equivalent in scripted pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989238/post-equivalent-in-scripted-pipeline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing `try-catch-finally` block.

```
node ('abc') {
    try {
        stage ('checkout'){
            some codes inside
        }

        stage ('build'){
            some code inside
        }

        stage ('test') {
            some code inside
        }

        stage ('deploy'){
            some code inside
        }

        stage ('notify'){
            Notification for JOB Success
        }
    }catch(e){
        Notification for JOB Failure
    }finally{

    }
}
```

Comment: @xxxSL you don't need anything in finally. `Success` Notification should be `last` stage in `try` block and `Failure` notification should be inside `catch` block as mentioned in code

Answer (score 0):

See official Jenkins documentation:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#finishing-up
(If you don't want to use declarative pipeline, see 'Toggle Scripted Pipeline' section).