# Code execution failure for post pipeline failure

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm building a pipeline using scripted pipeline and as I can see from https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/, for declarative pipeline, we can use post actions.

Similarly I tried in declarative pipeline -

```
node {
        stage("Stage 1") {
                script {
                    FAILED_STAGE=env.STAGE_NAME
                    echo "stage 1"
                }
        }
        stage("Stage 2") {
                script {
                    FAILED_STAGE=env.STAGE_NAME
                    echo "stage 2"
                    error "failed for some reason."
                }
        }
        stage("Stage 3") {
                script {
                    FAILED_STAGE=env.STAGE_NAME
                    echo "stage 3"
                }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            echo "Failed stage name: ${FAILED_STAGE}"
        }
    }
}
```

But I do not see failure block of post executed even if pipeline failed. Can you please help to understand if it has some different syntax for scripted pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `scripted pipeline` and not a `declarative pipeline` (see the difference [here](https://www.edureka.co/community/54705/difference-between-declarative-pipeline-scripted-pipeliine)). The syntax is completely different so you can't use a `post-stage` (existing for declarative pipeline) in a `scripted pipeline` (like your pipeline).

You have two options here.

1. You convert your `scripted pipeline` to a `declarative pipeline` (see syntax [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)) and simply use the `post-stage` like you have it used in your questoin. (I would prefer this option)

or

2. Implement the `post-stage` for your `scripted pipeline` by yourself in a `finally-block` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989238/post-equivalent-in-scripted-pipeline) SO question for help)